# Javascript function checking dates

Tags: javascript, function

Hi I am new to Javascript and am trying to create a function that checks two dates.  I have read it is useful to put the JS in the head part of the document, but this is not returning anything.  I am also new to stackoverflow so I hope I did this correctly.  :) Does anyone see the error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

var myDate = new Date(); // Your timezone!
var myEpoch = myDate.getTime()/1000;
var deadline = '1341596750.000';

document.write(myEpoch);
document.write("<br>",deadline);

if (myEpoch < deadline) {
  document.write("<p>Just in time!</p>");
} else {
  document.write("<p>Too late!</p>");
}

</head>
<body>

<br><br><br><br>http://www.epochconverter.com/
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where to start.... first, the code needs to live between `<script>` tags, the `document.write` will be prepended to the body and... well I'll stop there.

Comment: @TheZ: Actually, `document.write` works fine in the `<head>` :-P

Comment: @Rocket Sure, if prependeding is what you want, which in this case it is

Comment: @rocket: yeah, but you'll end up with `12345678<br><p>Just in time!</p>` in the head, which is not exactly valid.

Comment: thank you for the help guys.  and thanks for liking my question.  my points keep going up. YAY :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mention it's a script using `<script>`. Also you shouldn't output DOM in the `<head>` like you are doing with document.write. Manipulate the DOM like this instead:

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var myDate = new Date(); // Your timezone!
    var myEpoch = myDate.getTime()/1000;
    var deadline = '1341596750.000';

    document.write(myEpoch);
    document.write("<br>",deadline);

    if (myEpoch < deadline) {
      document.getElementById("useme").innerHTML("Just in time!");
    } else {
      document.getElementById("useme").innerHTML("Too late!");
    }
    </script>
    </head>
<body>

<p id="useme"></p>
```

Comment: Ah!! I didn't see i left out the JS tags.  Thank you!!

Comment: @JohnDoe Don't forget the `<facepalm></facepalm>` tag too

Comment: that didn't do anything.  what do facepalm tags do?

Comment: @JohnDoe: That was supposed to be a [joke](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/facepalm) =/

Comment: haha thanks for liking my question.  this site is actually pretty cool :)

Comment: ahah this kind of stuff happens to all of us, glad I could help.

Comment: as soon as i can i will approve your answer.  i guess its because my rank is not that high :)

Comment: @JohnDoe: You need to wait a few minutes before accepting an answer.  It's to allow others to answer too.  It's just how it works.